# Telegram Botfather how to edit the bot welcome message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I created a bot in telegram using botfather and I want to change the welcome message.

I can change he description, about, name, etc... but I cannot change the conversation the bot makes.

I just want the bot to say hello in my language.

Is there any command to edit this?

Answer (score 0):

I made it by installing ManyBot, with the  /setdescription method I changed the welcome message.